# Supabase getUser() error when no user is logged in

Tags: next.js, supabase

I'm building a Nextjs app with as Supabase backend. I have built a straight forward Signup and Authentication for the app following the examples on the Supabase website.

The main index page of the app has a getUser() function which is used to fetch the current user's information and allow permissions to certain parts of the app. This function works when a user is logged in however I am getting the errors below when there isn't a user logged in.

```
helpers.js:61          GET https://vvfxhlmmtgtpvbhzfgwn.supabase.co/auth/v1/user 401

AuthApiError: invalid claim: missing sub claim
at eval
```

Here below is the code I have for the getUser() function

```
  useEffect(() => {
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: { user }, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
    if (error) throw error;
    if (user) {
      const userId = user.id;
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      setUserId(userId);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
  }
}
getUser()
  }, [])
```

If anyone has any idea on what this error means or how it can be fixed, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would there be a better way to check/log the current user in the _app.tsx file?

Comment: Have you tried to use [the example](https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/blob/main/examples/nextjs/pages/index.tsx) on auth-helpers repo?

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look and added all the code needed in the _app.tsx component. This now allows me to use the useSession() or useUser() functions from '@supabase/auth-helpers-react' to get the current user and session. However the supabase.auth.signOut() function doesn't seem to change the status of useSession() or useUser() as they still return the same thing even if I delete the user info from the DB.

Comment: here is the repository I'm using https://github.com/rurigrass/citizen-quest